# Codeigniter Captcha not showing up image

Tags: codeigniter, captcha

i've been using captcha for codeigniter i working fine on my PC but somehow when i uploaded to the server it not generating the image, i've been trying with suggestion from other post from stackoverflow but it doesn't work

I've been check below point

1. GD is already enable
2. i already do the chmod 755 to assets directory with recursive mode

Please find below my code in controller

```
public function captcha_config() {
                $this->load->helper(array('captcha','form'));
                $vals = array(
                                'img_path' => '/var/www/html/assets/files/captcha/',
                                'img_url' => base_url().'assets/files/captcha/',
                                'img_width' => 150,
                                'img_height' => 30,
                                'expiration' => 7200
                        );
                        $cap = create_captcha($vals);
                        $this->session->set_userdata('capt',md5($cap['word']));
                        $image = $cap['image'];

                        //$data['captcha_img'] = $cap['image'];

                        //return $image;
                        var_dump($cap); //it shown bool(false)
        }
```

the result is

```
bool(false)
```

I've been change the path into this below, but also not working.

```
./assets/files/captcha/
```

-------------------------- Update 06-04-2016 --------------------------------

I got another clue

After i do debugging in helper (captcha_helper) i change some return False to be debugging mode. it shown following error

```
Message: imagejpeg(/var/www/html/assets/files/captcha/1465012057.5767.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I've done change the captcha directory to be chmod 777 but it seems doesn't work.

i've done change the ownership to be apache, i'm using this script to check the ownership from web, but still doesn't work ?

```
<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>
```

Why the captcha cannot write into that directory ?

Comment: There are 4 places where it returns false in the `create_captcha()` function. If the image path/url have not been set (your code set this so not a problem). If the image path is not a directory (I hope you have create a dir or this will be the issues). If the image path is not writable (I suspect this is your issue 0755 means it is writable by your user but only read/execute for other users, change permissions to 0777 to get around this). And finally if the GD lib is not installed (You claim it already is so should not be an issue). Good Luck :)

Comment: have you tried this `assets/files/captcha/`

Comment: @mic : i've been check the path, create a directory, make the directory writeable using chmod 666, GD already installer (i saw on PHP info), what was the issue ?, it's confusing

Comment: @RejoanulAlam : i've been change as your suggest but it doesn't impact

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Your i `img_path` is wrong. Try with this

```
 'img_path' => './assets/files/captcha/',
```

[CodeIgniter Captcha Helper Example - FormGet.com](https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-captcha-helper/)

Comment: hi @abdulla please see on my question above, i've been change into this also, but it's not working

Comment: @abdulla, relative paths are dangerous in includes. The reason for that, and the way to go, is explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

I've found clue because of this article, it is because SELinux is active on Centos 7.

https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/

Comment: Indeed, and you can troubleshooting this kind of issues, and find solutions for them, here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Exactly due to wrong image path it showing this error. use exact path and url in codeigniter its fine.

```
 'img_path'      => APPPATH.'../assets',
 'img_url'       => base_url().'/assets',
```

Answer (score 0):

First test if SELinux is active:
$ **sestatus**

If output is some like this:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Memory protection checking:     actual (secure)
Max kernel policy version:      33
```

Then disable it temporaly:
$ **sudo setenforce Permissive**

Try to generate a new captcha. If it works the cause is a SELinux permission problem.

Enable SELinux again:
$ **sudo setenforce Enforcing**

And apply a read/write policy to the captcha destination directory, in your case "/var/www/html/assets/files/captcha/"

$ **sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/html/assets/files/captcha/**

Test again.